# Is there a way to integrate Springs @ExceptionHandler with Joinfaces

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, joinfaces

i wanted to ask if there is a way to enable Springs `@ExceptionHandler` capabilities with Joinfaces/Primefaces.

For now i'm able to handle global `@ControllerAdvice` beans, but not if the `@ExceptionHandler` is inside the `@Controller` class.

Are there any suggestions on how to solve this topic?

Here is the code i wrote so far

```
@Slf4j
public class SpringJsfExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {

    public SpringJsfExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {
        final Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> queue = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();

        while (queue.hasNext()) {
            ExceptionQueuedEvent item = queue.next();
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext exceptionQueuedEventContext = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) item.getSource();

            try {
                Throwable throwable = exceptionQueuedEventContext.getException();

                FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

                handleException(context, (Exception) throwable);

            } finally {
                queue.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleException(FacesContext context, Exception throwable) {
        WebApplicationContext applicationContext = resolveApplicationContext(context);

        Collection<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers = listExceptionHandlerResolvers(applicationContext);

        for (HandlerExceptionResolver resolver : exceptionResolvers) {
            resolver.resolveException(request(context), response(context), null, throwable);
        }
    }

    private Collection<HandlerExceptionResolver> listExceptionHandlerResolvers(WebApplicationContext context) {
        return context.getBeansOfType(HandlerExceptionResolver.class).values();
    }

    private HttpServletRequest request(FacesContext context) {
        return (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    }

    private HttpServletResponse response(FacesContext context) {
        return (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    }

    private WebApplicationContext resolveApplicationContext(FacesContext context) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        return WebApplicationContextUtils.findWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext());
    }

}
```

```
public class SpringJsfExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {

    public SpringJsfExceptionHandlerFactory() {
    }

    public SpringJsfExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
        return new SpringJsfExceptionHandler(getWrapped() != null ? getWrapped().getExceptionHandler() : null);
    }
}
```

This works:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler
    public void handleCalculationException(CalculationException e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

This does not work:

```
@Data
@Controller
@ViewScoped
public class CalculatorController implements Serializable {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void handleCalculationException(CalculationException e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), e.getMessage()));
    }
[...]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: No

`@ExceptionHandler` is part of *Spring MVC*.

*Spring MVC* and JSF are separate web frameworks.

Joinfaces allows you to use JSF in a Spring Application, and you can also use *Spring MVC* in the same application. Every request will however either be handled by *Spring MVC* (i.e. the DispatcherServlet) or JSF (i.e. the FacesServlet).

Comment: Thanks, but Phil Webb did it 10 years ago, but now with Joinfaces i was wondering if it is somehow easier... 

The code above also works with Global @ExceptionHandler but not with ExceptionHandlers defined on Controller classes

https://github.com/philwebb/springfaces